# Using this vs object reference

Tags: javascript

I am wondering why I can not use `setTimeout(this.updateState, 1000);` in line 14.  The code works when I use `setTimeout(v.updateState, 1000)`.

```
var  GREEN = 1, YELLO= 2, RED = 3;
var v = {
  state: GREEN,
  updateState: function(){

    if(this.state == GREEN)
      this.state = YELLO;    
    else if(this.state == RED)
      this.state = GREEN;
    else
      this.state = RED;

    console.log(this.state);
    setTimeout(this.updateState, 1000); // this line works when I have setTimeout(v.updateState, 1000); wondering why this.updateState does not work
  }
};

setTimeout(v.updateState, 1000);
```

Comment: Try avoiding pasting line numbers, as it requires overhead for us if we want to test run code on our local.

Comment: `setTimeout(v.updateState.bind(v), 1000);` set `this` context